# Unable to access Twitter using ServiceConnect[]

Tags: webservices

I wrote a brief bit of MMA code to access Twitter and run a daily search on a specific keyword. The program has worked without any problems for the past several months. Most recently, I get an authorization error when I attempt to access Twitter via the built-in `ServiceConnect["Twitter"]` command:

```
twitter2 = ServiceConnect["Twitter"]

During evaluation of In[1]:= OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication::reqbdy: The service Twitter returned invalid request token response <<4224>>.

During evaluation of In[1]:= OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication::reqbdy: The service Twitter returned invalid request token response <<4224>>.

During evaluation of In[1]:= ServiceConnect::token: Could not obtain a request token for the OAuth service Twitter

During evaluation of In[1]:= ServiceConnect::invs: Twitter should be a valid Service name or ServiceObject, try using $Services

During evaluation of In[1]:= OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication::reqbdy: The service Twitter returned invalid request token response <<4224>>.

During evaluation of In[1]:= General::stop: Further output of OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication::reqbdy will be suppressed during this calculation.

During evaluation of In[1]:= ServiceConnect::token: Could not obtain a request token for the OAuth service Twitter

During evaluation of In[1]:= ServiceConnect::invs: Twitter should be a valid Service name or ServiceObject, try using $Services

Out[3]= ServiceConnect["Twitter"]
```

This code worked the prior day. Any suggestions on what could be going on?

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: Other similar questions on the site suggest that this might be temporary. Try again tomorrow and report back if it still doesn't work?